# Redirecting standard stream

Tags: c, linux, pipe, exec, fork

I'm trying to create pipes in the shell to redirect standard streams and I am stuck now.

When I try to run this code:

```
int fd[2];
pid_t pid;

pipe(fd);

pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
  // child process

  // redirect standard input and output
  dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);

  // close them (they are now redirected)
  close(fd[0]);
  close(fd[1]);

  char *input_argv[] = {"/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", ">", "out.txt", NULL};

  execv(input_argv[0], input_argv);
}
else if (pid > 0)
{
  // parent process

  waitpid(pid, NULL,0);
}
```

I got this error messages:

```
/bin/ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: cannot access out.txt: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what they mean, what cause them and how to fix them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All in all, the code doesn't make any sense. I think the best answer one can give here is to explain the most problematic parts:

```
  // redirect standard input and output
  dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
```

`fd[0]` is the reading end, `fd[1]` the writing end of a pipe. Whatever you write to `fd[1]` is available for read on `fd[0]`. So, this is just "short-circuiting" your stdio streams, something not usefull at all.

What you want to do with pipes normally is have one pipe per direction of communication between parent and child process (e.g. child should read from parent: `dup2()` the reading end to `STDIN_FILENO` in the child and write to the writing end from the parent).

```
  char *input_argv[] = {"/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", ">", "out.txt", NULL};
```

Now this doesn't make sense either. A `>` tells a **shell** to open a file for writing and `exec()` the child with a redirected `STDOUT_FILENO` already in place. It's certainly **not** an argument understood by `ls` here. You don't have a shell, you just `exec()` `ls` directly.

If your original intention was to mimic what the shell would do when given

```
ls > out.txt
```

you should just open the file `out.txt` for writing and in the child code `dup2()` the file descriptor of your opened file to `STDOUT_FILENO` before `exec()`ing `ls`. There's no need for a pipe in *this* scenario.

---

**edit** in case you want to understand what a shell does internally for `ls > out.txt`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* open file for writing */
    int outfd = open("/tmp/out.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 00666);
    if (outfd < 0)
    {
        perror("open()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* fork child */
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("fork()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        /* in the child, redirect stdout to our file */
        if (dup2(outfd, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
        {
            perror("dup2()");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        close(outfd);

        /* then execute 'ls' */
        execlp("ls", "ls", 0);

        /* only reached when execlp() fails: */
        perror("execlp()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* we don't need the output file in the parent process: */
    close(outfd);

    /* wait for child to complete */
    int childrc;
    waitpid(pid, &childrc, 0);

    /* return exit code of child process */
    return childrc;
}
```

Of course, the code of the actual shell looks different (doesn't have names hardcoded, uses `execv*` family of functions because it doesn't know the number of arguments in advance, and so on.)